# How to say "I regret to inform you that"?

Tags: idiom

How to express the following sentence in Latin?
I am after a good choice of structure, not a literal translation.

"I regret to inform you that our old teacher has died."

My suggestion is *Doleo te certiorem facere de morte magistri nostri veteris.*
Is *doleo te certiorem facere* or *doleo tibi narrare* an idiomatic and grammatical way of putting this?

Comment: I agree with *me pænitet*. But I'll also add that I'm fairly certain *doleo* + infinitive isn't a valid Latin construction. Others who know better may disagree! Also, my sense is that Latin prefers verbal constructions to nominal, so *de morte magistri nostri veteris* doesn't feel as Latinate as, say, *magistrum veterum mortuum esse*.

Comment: @JoelDerfner, I'm also uncertain if that is a valid construction. It will certainly be understood, but I don't think it's very good style. As for choosing between verbal and nominal constructions, it depends on the verb "inform" you pick. Some verbs might prefer *de*, some an ACI, some a subordinate clause, some an accusative object with a participle. I don't recall seeing *certiorem facere* without *de*.

Comment: Another suggestion might be: *de magistro nostro mortuo* I really don't think that *morte magistri* sounds contrived, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use *me poenitet* ([Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpaeniteo)) for this kind of construction.

In the specific example you cited, I would say: *Me poenitet te certiorem facere de morte magistri pristini nostri.*

Comment: L&S prefers *pæniet* (as I would), although *œ* is certainly attested. Just wondering, is there anything in particular that makes you prefer it?

Comment: @kkm, You're right about that--actually, the linked entry also uses *ae*. I use ecclesiastical pronunciation, which pronounces both the same, so I never paid too much attention to the variance in spelling.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to say this, but I like *paenitere*.

I would say: *Paenitet me tibi dicere de morte...*

Comment: Traupman, in the Bantam dictionary, recommends this as well.